# Failed to load libqxcb.so library while opening virtualbox on linux

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, virtualbox

I tried to reinstall libqt5gui5, libxcb1, libxcb1-dev, but it didnt help. I also searched for missing libraries for virtualbox with ldd, but I didnt found any.

Error from debug mode don't show the reason why plugin is not loaded

```
Qt WARNING: QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/damian/libs/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/damian/libs/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: "
Qt FATAL: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.
```

Don't work for me solutions from other threads with similar problem.

I have also libqxcb.so library in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/. Why dont it try to load this library?

Comment: One thing to check for is consistent platforms. Make sure you are launching 64-bit version of virtualbox. If your virtual box is built, for example, for i386, even when the `.so`, it cannot load it.

Comment: It is 64-bit version. It worked few days ago.

Comment: Another thing to try is setting `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and see if it outputs the debug information. It may be that the consistent `.so` is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/`, in that case you can try setting `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.